# Connect ODBC (without username & password) using DSN configured on windows

Tags: c#, .net

I have an requirement to develop windows form application in C# to connect with ODBC, select tables and its columns and at last get their data.

My exact need is to show list of DSN available on system and after selection that show its database and then show list of tables inside following with its column. Now after that I need to map all those columns with my local db column and periodically fetch data.

When I come to programming (refer below code) I see while I create an ODBC connection it ask for Username and password of database I need to connect (configured with DSN) even if I already provide those credentials while setting up DSN in control panel.

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=MyDSN;Uid=***;Pwd=****;");
string query = "";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
```

I need your help to confirm is it correct way or there is some other way also to connect db directly by DSN without using username and password as my customer is saying why I should provide credential in window application even if I already provided in DSN configuration.

Comment: What kind of Database are you trying to connect to? Odbc connection strings have to be very specific depending on the database you're trying to connect to. At least that's my experience with connecting to some very old mysql dbs over odbc.

Comment: Also - what's the underlying driver?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for edit made, I will take care for same in future.

Comment: @Mathew we need generic ODBC, my customer may use MYSQL or MSSQL to get data via DSN and they are also technical guy so he claims that we should not ask for password for our programming to get db tables via ODBC. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think that credentials, which you are providing in DSN Configuration wizard, are used only to fetch database list.

[image: DSN Configuration wizard - Connect to SQL Server]

> why I should provide credential in window application even if I already provided in DSN configuration

It is not necessary to provide credentials in DSN configuration.

Also you might want to create some service (proxy) on server, which could be configured to use specific credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance that your connection is safe, you can make your program use the stored DNS credentials (if they were previously configured) in Windows by adding the property/value "Trusted_Connection=Yes" within your config file in the  label:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConString" connectionString="Dsn=myDsnName;Trusted_Connection=Yes" providerName="System.Data.Odbc">
</connectionStrings>
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/odbc-dsn-using-in-Asp-Net/

A step by step article of ODBC DSN Using in ASP.Net.

I have followed this and tested. It works fine-

my code to pull a list of customer from db -

```
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(
    "SELECT * FROM [SH_Customer]",
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and my connection string in web config -

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Dsn=NayansUserDsn" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

Comment: @Kasier  as per my understanding you are using `windows authentication` but if I am using `sql authentication`, then how I will do it ?