# ODBC connection string (DSN)

Tags: c#, odbc, vsto

I'm developing a plugin for Excel (for customizable reporting and data extraction from various sources).

Right now I'm struggling with `ODBC connection` (DSN in particular). Even though I have created a dedicated DSN and pointed the app to use it, I had to specify the same information in the connection string (pwd, user name, db name etc.) to make it work.

I don't want to expose this type of information in the xml file and wonder if it possible to force the app to use the info from DSN only (or, as alternative, to encode the conn. string in the customized xml file)?

Comment: Please show what research you've done and explain why it didn't help.  This is a very common and widely-documented topic.  Not showing your research attracts down-votes, especially for common questions which may have duplicate answers.

Comment: There is nothing extraordinary. I have a file (a custom xml file containing connectivity information), like this one:
<Connections>
<Connection>
  <Alias>Azure</Alias>
  <Server>ODBC;Dsn=Azure_SQL;Uid=myUserName; Pwd=userPwd; Database=TestDb;</Server>
</Connection>
</Connections>
I don't understand why do I need to duplicate the same data I have already entered into DSN. I expected the following stuff to work:
<Server>ODBC;Dsn=Azure_SQL;</Server>
i.e. point the app. out into DSN only, but it doesn't work. I wouldn't say this issue is quite common.

Comment: From what I see here (https://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/) it requires user name and password anyway, but I don't want to keep them in shared xml file. For now it seems that the file/conn. string encryption is only option.

Comment: Found similar question without answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343435/connect-odbc-without-username-password-using-dsn-configured-on-windows), that's why I'm asking again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to encrypt connection string. Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
static void ToggleConfigEncryption(string exeConfigName)
{
    // Takes the executable file name without the
    // .config extension.
    try
    {
        // Open the configuration file and retrieve 
        // the connectionStrings section.
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

        ConnectionStringsSection section =
            config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
            as ConnectionStringsSection;

        if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            // Remove encryption.
            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        }
        else
        {
            // Encrypt the section.
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        // Save the current configuration.
        config.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Protected={0}",
            section.SectionInformation.IsProtected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jury, this is something I was considering as well. In case if I won't figure with DSN, this is a backup option for me.

Comment: @JohnBull, actually as suggested by MS, config encryption is preferred over DSN in terms of security: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx