# User DSN sql server ODBC connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, dsn

I am using Odbc sql server connection thr ODBC data source.
I added user DSN with uid and pwd.
I dont want to use **Trusted_Connection=yes;**

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
var conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Dsn=DsnName;Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
conn.Open();
```

When try to open connection, I am getting error like this
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'ABC\username'.

Also I dont want to add uid and pwd. It should be taken from DSN.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Do you get that error if you remove "Trusted_Connection=yes;"? - If you are always connecting to SQL Server is there a reason for using ODBC/a DSN in the fist place? (As opposed to SqlConnection)

Comment: If i remove then i get this  error   ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.

Comment: Trusted Connection uses a Windows Credential.  If the database is setup to only use a windows credential (group account) then a login will not work.  Also using a login may fail because Windows firewall my block a login.

Comment: This smells like a "double-hop" issue.  Please update your initial question with a brief description of your infrastructure - server machines, client machines, etc.

Comment: As I remember the password you enter when creating DSN is used on the DSN creation stage only (to get database list, server settings, etc.) and it is not stored in DSN itself. So you should either use Windows authentication (Trusted_Connection=yes) or specify UID/PWD properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect ODBC (without username & password) using DSN configured on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343435/connect-odbc-without-username-password-using-dsn-configured-on-windows)